# EXCEL: VLOOKUP directly to database

Tags: excel

I am looking for a solution to make a price list with Excel.
I want to write the KEYs from the Products in, lets say `A1` and then I want to get the price via a ODBC Connecition in `B1` which is stored in the database through the searching of he KEY.

I now figured out a working example:
I created a second table in excel where I imported the whole Table from database in this Excel table and Searched the table where the values from he database were stored in with `=VLOOKUP()` - problem is, that this is not very effective, because the FULL Database Table is stored in Excel - then the Excel instance fills the memory of the PC and the Excel file size goes easily to + 60 MB.

Is there a more efficient way? --> maybe is there a Addin or something to have a smiliar function like `=VLOOKUP()` to search in a Database Table directly instead of having a copy of the database in Excel stored?

Thank you..

Comment: How many keys are we talking here? If it's just the one, you could use VBA to update the SQL query with `SELECT * FROM your_DATATABLE WHERE art_KEY = " & yourSheet.Range("A1").Value2` or something similar like that.

Comment: @Notus_Panda: There would be, I think about 100 keys - but when update needs a few minutes it is no problem, because I only need to refresh data when the prices would change (like every month or every two months)

Comment: I doubt SQL would make a fuss about 100 keys, you could use something [like in the answer to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27985082/19353309) . You'll just have to adjust which values (the keys in  your A-column) it needs and ofc the SQL query itself to fit to your database (connection).